# How to make shades of black for a categorical variable using ggmap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggmap

I have a dataset that has a variable called quartile which is a categorical variable comprising values such as 1,2,3 and 4. I also have the corresponding latitude and longitudes for each observations. For visualization purposes I am plotting it using ggmap and getting different colors for each quartile values.

The code is as follows.

```
ggmap(mapdata)+
 geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = longitude, 
                            y = latitude, 
                            shape = factor(quartile),
                            color = factor(quartile)
                            ), 
            size = 1.8) + 
 scale_shape(solid = FALSE)
```

But I want to make a black and white picture which can also differentiate between the different quartile values. Is it possible to create a various shades of black? How to do it using ggmap?

Comment: Does adding `+ scale_colour_manual(values=grey(seq(0.1,0.9,length.out=4)))` give you the result you wanted?

Comment: Yes, it`s working! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also see `scale_color_grey`.

Comment: Yes, that also works. Thanks!